# I am trying to get the cpucapacity/cpuused value from the below json output from Ansible module am getting blank msg or error

Tags: ansible, json-query

clusters{
"DC0_C0":{
"datacenter":"DC0",
"moid":"domain-c9",
"drs_default_vm_behavior":"None",
"drs_enable_vm_behavior_overrides":"None",
"drs_vmotion_rate":"None",
"enable_ha":"None",
"enabled_drs":true,
"enabled_vsan":false,
"ha_admission_control_enabled":"None",
"ha_failover_level":"None",
"ha_host_monitoring":"None",
"ha_restart_priority":"None",
"ha_vm_failure_interval":"None",
"ha_vm_max_failure_window":"None",
"ha_vm_max_failures":"None",
"ha_vm_min_up_time":"None",
"ha_vm_monitoring":"None",
"ha_vm_tools_monitoring":"None",
"vsan_auto_claim_storage":false,
"hosts":[
{
"name":"esxi01.vsphere.local",
"folder":"/DC0/host/DC0_C0"
},
{
"name":"esxi02.vsphere.local",
"folder":"/DC0/host/DC0_C0"
},
{
"name":"esxi03.vsphere.local",
"folder":"/DC0/host/DC0_C0"
},
{
"name":"esxi04.vsphere.local",
"folder":"/DC0/host/DC0_C0"
}
],
"resource_summary":{
"cpuCapacityMHz":4224,
"cpuUsedMHz":87,
"memCapacityMB":6139,
"memUsedMB":1254,
"pMemAvailableMB":0,
"pMemCapacityMB":0,
"storageCapacityMB":33280,
"storageUsedMB":19953
},
"tags":[
{
"category_id":"urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceCategory:9fbf83de-7903-442e-8004-70fd3940297c:GLOBAL",
"category_name":"sample_cluster_cat_0001",
"description":"",
"id":"urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceTag:93d680db-b3a6-4834-85ad-3e9516e8fee8:GLOBAL",
"name":"sample_cluster_tag_0001"
}
]
}
}

I am using the below the filter

register: cluster_info

- debug: msg="{{ cluster_info.json_query('clusters[].resource_summary.cpuCapacityMHz')}}"

Comment: The syntax for using a filter is `variable|filter`, not `variable.filter`, which is what it looks like you're trying in that final `debug` task.

Comment: tried debug: msg="{{ cluster_info | json_query('clusters[].resource_summary.cpuCapacityMHz')}}" and still the same, I am able to print the results when i do this debug: msg="{{ cluster_info | json_query('clusters')}}". when i try to go further it is not printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query isn't working because `cluster_info["clusters"]` is a dictionary, not a list.  Asking for `clusters[]` doesn't make any sense. Try this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ cluster_info|json_query('clusters.*.resource_summary[].cpuCapacityMHz') }}"
```

You can read about [wildcard expressions](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#wildcard-expressions) in the JMESPath specification:

> The * syntax (referred to as a hash wildcard expression) will return
> a list of the hash element’s values. Any subsequent expression will
> be evaluated against each individual element in the list (this is
> also referred to as a projection).

I like to use [jpterm](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.terminal) for experimenting with JMESPath expressions.

Comment: It worked.. Thanks a lot for fixing and sharing the specification doc